# How to control check element from jquery dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used this [jQuery dropdown button](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown). This is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gayuevw8/1/). This is the step of this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, the functionality:

1. At the time of selecting one option, a new box will appearing containing the title of that option. For example, if you click on the "Low" on the dropdown, a new box will come containing text, "Low" with a cross button.

I've written the script like this:

```
$('.low-option input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('#low-box').show();
    } else {
        $('#low-box').hide();
    }
});
```

2. If you remove the boxes by clicking cross button, the box will be removed and adjacent checkbox will be unchecked.

So, I wrote this:

```
$('.option-box').on('click', '.cross', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();  
});

if($('#low-box').is(":hidden")) {
    $('.low-option input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);   
}
```

3. `div.option-content` is hidden at first. If any `div.option-box` will be visible, `div.option-content` will be visible too. If there is no `div.option-box` visible, `div.option-content` will be hidden always.

To do this, I wrote this:

```
var count = $('.option-content .option-box').is(":visible").length;
if (count > 0){
    $('.option-content').show();
} else{
    $('.option-content').hide();
}
```

But, my script is not working properly. As, I am not very good at jQuery, I can't find the reason and can't make it right way. Can you please help me removing the problem in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I rewrite your code so it will become more scalable.. The important part that you missed is to relate/connect the `checkbox` with your `option-box`, so it will be easier for you to `hide` or `show` related element.. Check out this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gayuevw8/2/).

```
$('.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('.option-content').show();
        $('.option-content #'+$(this).prop('id')).show();

    } else {
        $('.option-content #'+$(this).prop('id')).hide();
        if($('.option-content .option-box:visible').length == 0){
            $('.option-content').hide();
        }
    }
});

$('.option-box').on('click', '.cross', function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu #'+$(this).parent().prop('id')).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).parent().remove()
    if($('.option-content .option-box:visible').length == 0){
        $('.option-content').hide();
    }
});
```

Cheers..